# Change language for status pending, approve and rejected

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process, powerapp

I have a list in SharePoint and a PowerApp connected to it and use the approval flow for every new item.
But in the app I would like to change the standard text values Pending, Approved and rejected to In behandeling, Goedgekeurd en Geweigerd. Where can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered in the powerapps community and the suggested sollution works. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Change-language-status-Pending-approved-form-English-to-Dutch/m-p/536144/highlight/false#M164509

Set the OnStart property of App to following:

```
ClearCollect(
        Localization, 
        {TextID: "Approved", LocalizedText: "Goedgekeurd"}, 
        {TextID: "Pending", LocalizedText: "In afwachting"}, 
        {TextID: "Rejected", LocalizedText: "Afgekeurd"}
)
```

Then within theapp, please use the following formula to show the Status value (set the Text property of the Status Label to following:

```
LookUp(
   Localization,
   TextID = ThisItem.'Goedkeuringsstatus van inhoud',
   LocalizedText
)
```

Then re-oad the app.